# Android ContentProvider, URI with spaced (Date in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

Tags: android, datetime, character-encoding, uri, android-contentprovider

I consider what is best practice for parsing String to Uri that can be used with ContentProvider. This Uri should contain DateTime in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

```
'content://authority/basepath/someId/12/date/YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

I can make on this date `String.replace(' ', '+');` 
and then `uri.getPathSegments().get(4).replace('+', ' ')`

But maybe there is some better approach to this problem?

It seems that such URI isn't matched by UriMatcher in ContentProvider.update()

`content://com.xxx.provider.XXXProvider/learning_stats/profile/1/access_date/2015-04-08+11:40:24`

and this is my UriMatcher definition:

```
uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/profile/#/access_date/#", ROW_FOR_PROFILE_AND_ACCESS_DATE);
```

Comment: when I changed to uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/profile/#/access_date/*", ROW_FOR_PROFILE_AND_ACCESS_DATE); it seems to work with + replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in UriMatcher, "#" means numbers, "*" means text or exact. Check the source code in [/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/UriMatcher.java](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/UriMatcher.java#161)

I don't think there's necessary to do the replacement, Uri Builder would encode your date string,

```
    Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("content").path("/authority/basepath/someId/12/date/YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS").build();
    String date = uri.getPathSegments().get(5);
```

The encoded path is,

```
/authority/basepath/someId/12/date/YYYY-MM-DD%20HH%3AMM%3ASS
```

As you see, the character ':' should also be replaced, then decoded path is,

```
/authority/basepath/someId/12/date/YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

Or using millisecond value returned from `Date.getTime()` instead of the Date String.

```
'content://authority/basepath/someId/12/date/12345434'
```

`getTime()` Returns this Date as a millisecond value. The value is the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970, midnight GMT.

It's easy to parse the time,

```
Date time = new Date(12345434l);//12345434 is the value from URI.
```

Comment: I would prefer to rather encode date than convert to timestamp. It seems that may simple plus replacement causes that uri its matched by UriMatcher.

Comment: ok I try this solution with new Uri.Builder() cause I have been using Uri.parse(). It seems ok as the client doesn't need to know about replacing " " to "+" :)

Comment: Also note that,  in UriMatcher, "#" means numbers, "*" means text or exact

Comment: but isn't it that "*" takes all remaining characters in Uri also  / , etc. ?, "#" seems to work perfectly ok for String

Comment: ok here # doesn't work, and with * your solution works very well :) I used rather: scheme().authority().appendPath().appendPath() .... . build()